# Oblivion GOTY says it requires a CD to uninstall the game, how can I uninstall without it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have *The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion GOTY Edition* installed on my machine (Windows 10). I am wanting to remove it since I no longer play it, but when I try to run the uninstaller, I get the following error:

[image: Uninstaller message]

This happens whether I use the uninstaller in the Oblivion folder, or if I go to the "Apps & Features" section of Windows 10 settings to uninstall a program.

Unfortunately, I have lost the CD, and it seems kind of ridiculous to have to find it just so I can remove the game from my computer. Is there an alternative way to uninstall Oblivion without the disc?

Comment: For what its worth even having the original disc probably wouldn't work since the 64-bit versions of Windows 10 don't support SecuRom disk-based copy protection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to uninstall it I think you'll have to do it manually. Hurray for DRM!

In order to do this you'll have to do delete files from three locations; **the install path**, **the game data path** and **the registry**.

---

*Before you begin I suggest taking a backup of at least the registry since messing around with that can cause problems especially if you don't know what you are doing.*

---

### The Install path

This is where you installed the game to in the first place. Generally it will be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Bethesda Softworks\`. Delete the Oblivion folder. If you chose a custom location you'll have to find it. You can easily find it by right clicking the shortcut on the desktop or from wherever you launch the game, and select `open file location`.

### The Game Data

This is where the game automatically saves your save files and other things such as user preferences. If you wish to delete these go to `C:\Users\[insert PC name here]\My Documents\My Games\` and delete the `Oblivion` folder. If you think you may play the game later on you may want to leave this folder alone and it will be available the next time you install the game.

### The Registry

The registry entries won't take up much space so you may wish to just leave it but if you wish you could try either doing it manually or using some tool. To do it manually: open up the registry by pushing <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> and typing `regedit`, hit enter and the *Registry Editor* should open up.

Just search through the registry using the Edit > Find option for keywords such as `Oblivion` and then delete all entries.

A tool such as CCleaner searches through the registry and deletes unused registry keys. The Oblivion entries should be unused at this stage and thus be deleted when you run CCleaner.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the registry entries are for? Is it for showing up in the Uninstall programs list? Something else? That would help me determine whether or not it's worth going through that.

Comment: I don't know, it could be a vast range of things but generally for games they're not too important, I'd suggest leaving it. If you want to reinstall Oblivion you may run into some issues so run CCleaner, it's simple to use. , and a fresh install will probably work after that. It's not easy to manually delete from the registry I don't recommend it. Remember the total size of all the registry entries will be negligible so if you're not going to be installing it again just leave it alone.

Comment: I agree with Aequitas.  Often the registry isn't worth the trouble.  The only time it seems to have an impact is when you try to reinstall the software at a later date.  I can't remember the game, but there was a case where I needed to change a registry key for the CD drive once.  Between removing and reinstalling my CD drive changed letter, which led to me getting problems loading the game because the reinstall re-used existing keys.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to delete the installation folder manually. Aside from your save games that should delete practically everything that was installed.  The default install folder is `C:\Program files (x86)\Bethesda Softworks\Oblivion` so use Explorer to navigate to the `Bethesda Softworks` folder and then delete the `Oblivion` folder.  If you want to delete your save games as well they're stored in `C:\Users\Your Name\My Documents\My Games\Oblivion`.

If you then go and try to uninstall the game using Apps & Features it should complain that it can't find the uninstaller and ask if you want to remove the game from the list.